# Wrap img in <li> tag

Tags: jquery, youtube

I have a jquery code to pull the videos from youtube channel and display as thumbs and play when thumb is clicked..

The problem is that currently the images are naked and I need them to be wrapped in `<li>` tag so that I create a carousel out of it.

Here is the jquery code

```
(function() {
    function createPlayer(jqe, video, options) {
        var ifr = $('iframe', jqe);
        if (ifr.length === 0) {
            ifr = $('<iframe width="260" height="146" scrolling="no">');
            ifr.addClass('player');
        }
        var src = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + video.id;
        if (options.playopts) {
            src += '?';
            for (var k in options.playopts) {
                src+= k + '=' + options.playopts[k] + '&';
            }  
            src += '_a=b';
        }
        ifr.attr('src', src);
        jqe.append(ifr);  
    }

    function createCarousel(jqe, videos, options) {
        var car = $('div.youtubecarousel', jqe);
        if (car.length === 0) {
            car = $('<ul>');
            car.addClass('youtubecarousel');
            jqe.append(car);

        }
        $.each(videos, function(i,video) {
            options.thumbnail(car, video, options);
        });
    }

    function createThumbnail(jqe, video, options) {
        var imgurl = video.thumbnails[0].url;
        var img = $('img[src="' + imgurl + '"]');
        if (img.length !== 0) return;
        img = $('<img>');
        img.addClass('thumbnail');
        jqe.append(img);
        img.attr('src', imgurl);
        img.attr('title', video.title);
        img.click(function() {
            options.player(options.maindiv, video, $.extend(true,{},options,{playopts:{autoplay:1}}));
        });

    }

    var defoptions = {
        autoplay: false,
        user: null,
        player: createPlayer,
        carousel: createCarousel,
        thumbnail: createThumbnail,
        loaded: function() {},
        playopts: {
            autoplay: 0,
            egm: 1,
            autohide: 1,
            fs: 1,
            showinfo: 0
        }
    };


    $.fn.extend({
        youTubeChannel: function(options) {
            var md = $(this);
            md.addClass('youtube');
            md.addClass('youtube-channel');
            var allopts = $.extend(true, {}, defoptions, options);
            allopts.maindiv = md;
            $.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/' + allopts.user + '/uploads?alt=json-in-script&format=5&callback=?', null, function(data) {
                var videos = [];
                var feed = data.feed;
                $.each(feed.entry, function(i, entry) {
                    var video = {
                        title: entry.title.$t,
                        id: entry.id.$t.match('[^/]*$'),
                        thumbnails: entry.media$group.media$thumbnail
                    };
                    videos.push(video);
                });
                allopts.player(md, videos[0], allopts);
                allopts.loaded(videos, allopts);
                allopts.allvideos = videos;
                allopts.carousel(md, videos, allopts);


            });
        }
    });

})();

$(function() {
    $('#youtubeplayer').youTubeChannel({user:'autoxtv'});
});
```

Html code I am using:

`<div id="youtubeplayer">
</div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you ask about can be achieved using jQuery's `.wrap` method:

```
$('img').wrap('<li />');
```

You could try adding `img.wrap('<li />');` to your `createThumbnail` function.

Comment: Hi, this works great for me...

just a little a off topic help if you can, I need to convert these items to jcarousel but its not working:

Here is the code : `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#youtubecarousel').jcarousel({
        auto: 4,
        wrap: 'circular',
  scroll: 1,
  vertical: true,
    });
});`

Comment: This looks fine. Do you have <ul id="youtubecarousel"> in your markup?

Comment: yes thats generated by the code I have placed in the initial Question, even I am using other two instances of jcarousel in my page and they are working fine...

Comment: In your code you create <ul> with a *class* youtubecarousel, not id.. Then try $('ul.youtubecarousel').jcarousel...